# How to make multisyntax highlight in vim using in text triggers?

Tags: vim

I'm working on system which must work on files with multi syntax: any data file can conists of C++ Python JavaScript and some documentation markup text **in one data file** (something like multilanguage literate programming).

Is it possible to trigger vim syntax highlighting (filetype) in mid of buffer by some triggering keyword in text itself on the fly, like

```
.doc Let's view our data object as AST tree:
.py
class AST:
  tag = 'sym' .doc here we set 'sym'bolic unversal data type .py
  def __init__(self,V): self.val = V .doc \emph{any data can be represented as string} .py
...

.doc
Now we need ...
```

Can vim switch between `filetype=latex` end `filetype=python` on `.doc` and `.py` triggers ?

Comment: This Vim tip seems to be dealing with the same kind of thing - http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Different_syntax_highlighting_within_regions_of_a_file

Answer (score 0):

Yes, additional syntaxes can be included in the current one, cp. `:help :syn-include`. Setting this up is a bit complex, though. My [SyntaxRange plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4168) helps with that. For your example, the following calls will work:

```
:call SyntaxRange#Include('^\.doc', '\n\.\@=', 'tex')
:call SyntaxRange#Include('^\.py', '\n\.\@=', 'python')
```